# MQTT Timeout when trying to connect to TLS enabled broker in unity3d

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mqtt, tls1.2

I am building an AR app in Unity and I need to connect to an MQTT broker with TLS protocol enabled. I am able to connect to non TLS enabled MQTT brokers successfully(In unity), and I can use the certificate the admin gave me with this program http://www.mqttfx.org/ to connect to the TLS enabled broker successfully. But when I attempt to connect to the TLS enabled server with the m2mqtt library for c# in Unity, I get a timeout exception and never receive a response from the broker. This is the code I am using to test the connection. I am just attempting to make a successful connection then disconnect.

```
X509Certificate certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("filePath");

// Connect to this broker address at port 1883 with tls enabled 
client = new MqttClient(brokerAddress, port, true, certificate);

// Generate a client id
string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 

// Connect to the client with credentials
byte code = client.Connect(clientId, username, password;

// Disconnect       
client.Disconnect ();
```

This exception occurs during connect:

```
MqttCommunicationException: An application exception has occurred.
uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.SendReceive (System.Byte[] msgBytes, Int32 timeout) (at Assets/MQTT/scripts/MqttClient.cs:953)
uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.SendReceive (uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgBase msg, Int32 timeout) (at Assets/MQTT/scripts/MqttClient.cs:976)
uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.SendReceive (uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgBase msg) (at Assets/MQTT/scripts/MqttClient.cs:964)
uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect (System.String clientId, System.String username, System.String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, System.String willTopic, System.String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod) (at Assets/MQTT/scripts/MqttClient.cs:456)
uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect (System.String clientId, System.String username, System.String password, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod) (at Assets/MQTT/scripts/MqttClient.cs:395)
ConnectionManager.connectToMQTTBroker () (at Assets/Scripts/ConnectionManager.cs:55)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: SSL auth is not supported with mqtt

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean please? I am using this certificate to successfully connect using MQTT.FX using TLS protocol version 1.2. So I am confused by what you are trying to say.

Comment: Also http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-security-fundamentals-tls-ssl

Comment: I believe I've seen this problem before on SO. The OP emailed the author of that API and found that that is does not support SSL. I can't find that post anymore but will link it if I come across it again. This was about 2 years ago so maybe they support it now....

Comment: I found this article that is dated December of 2015 that says they support it now. Maybe that was before they started supporting it? https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/2015/12/06/324/

Comment: I partially figured it out. The third party app is sending the certificate but for some reason the m2mqtt library is not. I found this out using wireshark.

Comment: Well you claimed that it supports it now so I don't know what to tell you. I suggest you contact the people that made it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M2Mqtt does not Support TLS_V2 , Because of what we cant use certificates with unity. This is due to .Net FrameWork Version Support . For Certificates we use TLSV_2 QOS Level for connecting which is supported from .Net 4 and above , But Unity has support for only .Net 3.5 Version.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. This is exactly what I meant, thank you for explaining it better, I have removed my bland answer. I solved this problem by using extern functions in my Unity code to interact with an Objective-C MQTT client on the iOS layer from Unity. I hope that helps anybody that runs into this problem.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old topic but I have the same issue right now. Unity does support .Net 4 now, but even after changing it I failed to use certificates with Unity (I get the TlsException: Handshake failed), is there a way to fix it?